# Establishment not shown in google map autocomplete form

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I refer to following web page to extract establishment from place autocomplete.

[Place Autocomplete Address Form](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

I replace the component form with following and add input field with same id. However, the problem i faced is that the establishment is not returned for many of the case. This value for establishment does exist when i check the address with following url. However, it seems that it is not able to extract the information. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=XXX

```
var componentForm = {
  establishment: 'establishment',
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};
```